# NSPredicate for checking if a CoreData attribute matched with other variable satisfy a criteria

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity with three fields

```
Task {
   Active BOOL
   Recurrent Int
   Started date
}
```

'Recurrent' is the delay for a task to happen. If task has a given 'Started' and a 'Recurrent' of 15, means it have to be repeated 15 days after 'Started'.
I want to build an NSPredicate for finding all entities that at a given date need to be executed.

For example supposing there's one entity in store with 'Started' = 15/12/2011 'Recurrent' = 15, then querying CoreData on 29/12/2011 give no result. Doing a query on 30/12/2011 will give a result because 15 days has passed since 'Started'.

I would easily deal with this with SQL with some math operation but I have absolutely no idea on how to accomplish this using NSPredicate, considering that the query is done directly on field.
I would like to stay with NSPredicate because it's an iOS application with UITableView and I am planning to use an NSFetchedResultsController, but if not possible, an NSArray of entities would be fine.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easy" answer would be to store `recurrent` as a date as well.  Or to store a `recurrentResolved` value that is a date and fetch against that.

The less easy and uglier option is to load all tasks and do the calculation in memory (in a convenience method) and then do a second `NSPredicate` against the objects.  Once they are loaded into memory your `NSPredicate` can take advantage of methods in your subclass.

I would recommend the first option.  The second is far more expensive.

Comment: Could you use predicateWithBlock here as well? I agree with your first option as the best, though.

Comment: After the objects have been fetched into memory yes.  During the `NSFetchRequest`; no, that translates down into actual SQL.

Comment: I know it's my fault, but when using CoreData, sooner or later lead me always to a dead end road. I don't know for the first option, I need to use this thing in a UITable that can be filled with any date future or past. That's the need of the calculation. What about NSExpression with custom function ?

Comment: You can't do calculations in a `NSFetchRequest`.  There is no exception or way around it.  It is a limitation and you can file a radar but that functionality does not exist.  Therefore you are left with two options; pre-calculate the value or filter twice.